# Stop Outlook from acting on IMAP Alerts

Tags: outlook, imap

I have an IMAP server which sets an "account approaching quota" alert when an account is above 85%.  For the majority of our users who are using Thunderbird, this works great as they receive the notice once to twice a day as a gentle reminder.  Our few die-hard outlook users on the other hand get an annoying popup as often as their account gets polled.  Does anyone know of a way to tell outlook to reuse IMAP connections to avoid this problem (or alternatively to disable Outlook reporting of alerts altogether)?

Comment: What are you using as your IMAP server?

Comment: We currently are using CommuniGate, thought this problem would be endemic to any environment with pretty much any IMAP server plus Outlook as a client.  Most places just disable quota alerts on the server side, but I'd much rather keep the alerts in place (since they work well for the majority of our users) and just somehow "fix" the outlook users.